# Problem with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, google-chrome, opera

```
var obj = {
'51' : { 'name':'name1'},     
'66' : { 'name':'name2'},     
'58' : { 'name':'name3'}
};
$(function() {
    s = '';
    $.each(obj, function(k, v) {
        s += ' '+k;
    });
    alert(s);
});
```

In IE and Firefox it's 51 66 58, but in Opera and Chrome it's 51 58 66
Why Jquery.each() sort by key in opera, chrome?
What can i do to keep native order?

p.s if array keys is a string, result 51j 66j 58j
perhaps opera and chrome try to convert keys to integer where it's possible

```
var obj = {
"51j" : { "name":"name1"},    
"66j" : { "name":"name2"},    
"58j" : { "name":"name3"}
};
```

Comment: It's object keys, and they're strings whatever happens.

Comment: it's seems opera and chrome do not think so..

Comment: In JS, obj[1] and obj['1'] are equivalent. However, as already explained the order of for..in iteration is left undefined by the specification. Browsers can return the values in ANY order and still behave "correctly" per the specification. Over time, compatibility with the web and other browsers has forced insertion order most of the time, but this is still not reliable as you've discovered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript objects are unordered. There is no guarantee about which order the keys should come out when you loop over them and JS engines are free to implement whatever storage and retrieval systems they like.

If order matters, use an array: `[]`

This can contain objects:

```
[
    { 'foo' : '1234', 'bar' : '5678' },
    { 'foo' : 'abcd', 'bar' : 'qwer' },
    { 'foo' : 'ldng', 'bar' : 'plma' }
]
```

Comment: If i get it via ajax request?

Comment: @ncsft: If you cannot change the `JSON` you need to read it in and sort it yourself, before processing.